# pyqt embed in photoshop

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

This is complex to explain, I hope this will not end up being a vague question getting vague answers.
If this is not the right place to ask this, you may help me to find the proper one.

I have a plugin for Photoshop based on the Listener, so it captures any input from the user. 
The plugin creates a python module (called here "ps") containing basically the hInstance and the hwnd of the photoshop window.

Then this plugin, using plain python commands in the plugin for the module like those

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import Photoshop");
PyRun_SimpleString("Photoshop.showTools()");
```

will load a special module (here called "Photoshop") that will initialize pyqt and using the QtWinMigrate and the ps module to get the hInstance like this: `QMfcApp.pluginInstance(ps.GetPluginInstance())`, will start pyqt in photoshop. Here an example code of the Photoshop module using the ps module:

```
from PyQt4.QtWinMigrate import QMfcApp
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPushButton
import ps #this is implemented in the photoshop plugin (based on the Listener plugin)

#create the plugin instance here
app=QMfcApp.pluginInstance(ps.GetPluginInstance())
def showTools():
    box = QPushButton()
    box.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Again then, the sequence is like this:
When the plugin starts in photoshop "ps" module is created, then it will load the "Photoshop" module that will load and bind properly pyqt. In the "Photoshop" module I can load any python module, widgets are properly working and everything works really well inside Photoshop.

But now the problem is: using Wacom tablets in Photoshop loose stroke sensitivity, the driver works and everything else works but the pressure sensitivity.

Apparently `QMfcApp.pluginInstance` will install an event filter to drive the Qt event loop while photoshop still owns the event loop. ( http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtwinmigrate/qmfcapp.html )
and on the paper looks fine to me.. but I could not manage to solve this by myself and I tried, more or less carefully, different approaches:

- the listener plugin is not the problem. If Listener plugin runs but python is not initialized sensitivity works fine.
- python itself is not a problem. If the listener starts python without gui nor pyqt, then works fine.
- as soon as I call pluginInstance which should create the `QApplication` the issue starts and pressure is lost from the tablet. Even with the small code I wrote before.
  Someone may have put pyqt as a plugin somewhere else, since the only purpose of `QMfcApp` is apparently this one. There is something I can configure to make it work? Is a known issue? 
  I would rather keep the approach (instead of connecting to photoshop externally like with COM)

I am not able to post the entire code here but let me know if you need something.. I probably can show more.
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I suspect that the fact that qt also loads the wintab driver is conflicting with however photoshop communicates with the wacom tablet. This doesn't surprise me as Qt has pretty poor wintab support and there are no Qt developers left who appear to care about it! Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be any way to disable wintab support at runtime. I see two options for you: 1) Try and use PyQt5 and see if that fixes the problem (Qt5 has no wintab support [yet]) 2) recompile Qt/PyQt4 with the `-no-wintab` option

Comment: Assuming you're not putting more source code here because you are developing something commercial, I'm guessing that you might have a commercial PyQt license. If so, they may be willing to provide you with a version of PyQt without wintab support (I imagine they are quite helpful to paying customers!)

Comment: You put me in the right track!
Together with this patch [rmawatsons-qt](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/merge_requests/2538) I may be able to solve this and other problems I find.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Good find! Hopefully it won't be too hard to build PyQt using this patch.

Comment: no problem. wacom pressure works fine now :)